# ¿Cómo se puede diferenciar entre "answers" y "responses" cuando ambas pueden traducirse como "respuestas"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, sinónimos

En el sitio Meta de Stack Overflow en español se ha formulado la siguiente pregunta interesante: [¿Deberíamos cambiar los literales de “respuestas” en la pantalla de actividad?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4531/83). En ella se expone el hecho que la interfaz de Stack Overflow diferencia en el perfil de usuario entre tres cosas distintas:

- '**answers**', respuestas que uno ha publicado en el sitio
- '**responses**', interacciones de otra gente hacia uno: respuestas, comentarios, revisiones de las publicaciones.

  - '**answers**', respuestas que ha recibido uno (nótese que es un subconjunto del bloque anterior).

En el interfaz castellano todo ello se ha traducido por ***respuestas***, pero se comenta de forma interesante que tal vez fuera bueno encontrar algún término para traducir las 'responses' de una forma diferente.

[WordReference indica](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=response) que la traducción de 'response' puede ser básicamente una de estas:

- respuesta
- reacción
- contestación

La primera es la actual y no nos serviría, mientras que la segunda me chirría un poco, por aquello que nos interesan las *reacciones entrantes*, es decir, las de otro usuario hacia nosotros. *Contestación* me evoca demasiado a *respuesta* y me costaría interpretar que en ese grupo puedan caber cosas como las revisiones de usuarios.

¿Se os ocurre alguna palabra para absorber el significado de 'response', en el sentido de agrupar todas las interacciones *entrantes* de la comunidad hacia un usuario?

Comment: Mencionaste "interacciones". A mi me suena bien.

Comment: Un problema es que "responses" en inglés tampoco es un término adecuado...

Comment: "Reacciones" no me parece mal. Son después de todo eso mismo: algo que se produce en respuesta (!) a otra cosa. "Interacciones" tiene el problema de que es bidireccional.

Comment: A mí me gusta *reacción* o *intervención* o *aportación*.

Comment: Es interesante que en la entrada para Jeopardy en Wikipedia, se usa respuestas tanto para answers como para responses.  En Jeopardy las respuestas son preguntas, Y las pistas son respuestas.  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La definición de [response](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/response) en el Diccionario de Cambridge es:

> an answer or reaction

En Stack Exchange, la pestaña "Responses" agrupa:

- respuestas de otros usuarios a preguntas propias
- comentarios de otros usuarios en relación a contribuciones propias (es decir, a preguntas, respuestas, comentarios, revisiones o votos de cierre/reapertura propios, entre otras).
- revisiones hechas por otros usuarios en las publicaciones propias

En línea con la definición del diccionario de Cambridge, todo esto son **reacciones** de la comunidad a las contribuciones propias. Se podría argumentar que los votos (positivos y negativos) también son reacciones, pero también en inglés se podría decir que los votos son responses ("The answer received a positive response from the community").

Por tanto, creo que el término más parecido a **responses** en español es **reacciones**.

En cuanto a especificar que las reacciones son *entrantes*, esto es difícil con una sola palabra. En inglés, ninguno de los términos "answers" o "responses" tiene esta connotación (una "answer" o "response" puede ser escrita por el usuario o recibida por el usuario). Por eso hay un "texto flotante" que aparece al posar el ratón sobre una pestaña, que dice en un caso "answers you provided" y en otro caso "your recent responses" (este segundo es bastante ambiguo en mi opinión, y yo lo cambiaría por "responses from the community" o "responses to your posts"). Mi propuesta sería por tanto:

- una pestaña **Respuestas** con texto flotante "respuestas que proporcionaste".
- una pestaña **Reacciones** con texto flotante "reacciones a tus publicaciones"

Sin embargo, si es imprescindible expresar el sentido *entrante* en el título de la pestaña, yo propondría **Notificaciones** o **Bandeja de entrada**, que es casi la única forma de expresar esto sin ambigüedad.

Comment: Si bien no es relevante para la respuesta en sí, lo de _respuestas de otros usuarios a comentarios propios_ no es exactamente así, sino más bien _comentarios dirigidos a uno_, pues no siempre son como respuesta a un comentario previo. Por ejemplo, este comentario mío te aparecerá sin que haya habido comentario previo tuyo :)

Comment: @fedorqui Es verdad. Sin embargo, esos comentarios siempre son en respuesta a una contribución propia (una pregunta, respuesta, comentario o revisión). No se puede escribir un comentario a alguien en un post en el que ese alguien no haya interactuado en una de esas cuatro formas. Por eso me gusta "reacción". He actualizado mi respuesta.